# Robocopy can't handle paths containing scandic characters

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, robocopy

I am trying to copy folders with Robocopy from Windows 2008 server to Windows 2012 server.
Server language setting is english.

I use command like this:

```
robocopy "C:\Files\Folder with äö in name\Source" "D:\Folder with äö also" /MIR
```

Command fails like this:

```
Source : C:\Files\Folder with õ÷ in name\Source\
Dest : D:\Folder with õ÷ also\

...
ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory C:\Files\Folder with õ÷ in name\Source\
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Bat-file that uses this command is created with Notepad. I have tried creating it with all encodings offered by notepad. None of them work, examples above come from ANSI encoding.

If I create test folders that don't contain foreign characters Robocopy works without erros.

How can Robocopy deal with Scandic characters?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with a normal directory?

I found that while the öä etc are not correctly logged in the log files robocopy processes them correctly.

Comment: It works OK with directories that don't have those foreign characters in path.